# The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, updates, google-chrome, authentication, gnupg

After executing this command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

I get this error

```
W: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I've seen past inquiries on same issue but the answers given are specific to other repositories. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is something Google needs to fix on their end, by rebuilding their apt repository in the more secure and correct manner.

Comment: Look for a 404 in the output of `apt-get update`. If it's there, it may be that you can solve this issue by changing the repository URL from `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main` to `https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main` (e.g. in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` or wherever you're adding the Chrome apt repo)

Answer (score 30):

The previous answer was wrong (Traxidus Wolf).

That issue (reference) wasn't an error but just a message for that guy to answer yes or no (change from Google Inc to LLC), it happened to all last week after an update.

The problem was that `apt-get` is low level now and `apt` more user-oriented so `apt-get` did not ask for the user interaction.

---

This error is different:

The "key" is "**repository can't be authenticated**"

IMHO... you don't have the key of the repo

To solve that just use this command:

```
$ wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/

In the past you could add any repo you wanted, now you need their gpg key otherwise doesn't work.

Comment: use this command instead of: `wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key    add -
`

Comment: @ParisaN why use `jenkins.io` instead of the official Google key repository?

Answer (score 5):

As per the answer at this post » [How to update Google Chrome 70 after change in 'Origin' value? '](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090676/how-to-update-google-chrome-70-after-change-in-origin-value)
Due to the low level of apt-get the prompt isn't provided.

Run: "apt update"

It will give you a "y/n" prompt, chose "y" and from then on the error and note will be treated.

Answer (score -2):

This seems to remove the error.

Edit file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
Comment all the lines by putting # symbol as first character.
Close file.