# How to update Google Chrome 70 after change in 'Origin' value?

Tags: apt, updates, google-chrome, ppa

I have Google Chrome Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Today, after running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade`, I saw:

```
E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

I looked at the *man* page for *apt-secure* but it's pretty technical and difficult, at least for me, to follow.

So how do I fix this issue?

---

Edit: for now, I've removed the existing Google Chrome ppa from Software Sources and then ran `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt full-upgrade` successfully with the following being installed/upgraded successfully:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-netifaces
The following packages will be upgraded:
  netplan.io nplan ppp
3 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

This issue has existed [for some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942353/e-repository-http-dl-google-com-linux-chrome-remote-desktop-deb-stable-relea/50942354):

> The error message clearly shows that this has to do with Google changing its name from Google, Inc to Google LLC. The error message shows what's wrong, but does not tell us what command to run to fix this problem.
>
> How can I accept this change explicitly as the message says?

As stated in the question linked to above from June 2018, the issue related to **`chrome-remote-desktop`** and the solution is simply to run `sudo apt update` and to respond with `y` at the prompt.

This is what I see when I run just `sudo apt update` **without chaining it with `sudo apt upgrade`**:

```
E: Repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Google, Inc.' to 'Google LLC'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N] y
Get:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1,130 B]
```

Running just `sudo apt update` provides the `[y/N]` prompt.

Comment: changing from `sudo apt-get update` to `sudo apt update` fixed it for me.

Comment: @sdexp It would be helpful if it was also made as an answer since it wouldn't be noticed in the comments.

Answer (score 24):

For anyone that is using Ansible or similar tools to deal with this prompt on multiple hosts, here is what I found worked for me.

While `apt -y update` worked in an interactive environment I couldn't get it to work in Ansible's ad hoc env. I tried various combinations of options and force-yes options but none seemed to work.

There is probably a better way but this is the command that seemed to get the change accepted on all the hosts:

```
apt-get update -y --allow-releaseinfo-change
```