# Unable to update Kubuntu 18.04 - Opera/Chrome PPA changed "origin value" error

Tags: package-management, google-chrome, opera

I'm very new to Ubuntu.  I have Kubuntu 18.04 installed on my laptop and have been updating it with no problem, until today.  I selected to 'update all', then it got stuck with a message popping up as below:

[image: Settings + update popup]

I cannot close the page or reset the update.  Haven't tried to reboot the laptop yet, though I suspect I will get stuck on the same thing when I try to update again.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090676/how-to-update-google-chrome-70-after-change-in-origin-value. You'll need to open a terminal and run `sudo apt update`: you'll get a prompt. Answer **yes** to that. Then update/upgrade as normal.

Comment: Also, what distro are you using? How do you have **Discover** on your system? Anyway, whenever Discover stalls, which is not infrequent, open a terminal and run `pkill plasma-discover`.

Comment: @DKBose Thank you so so much for the help. Got the system updated and the Discover off. I am using Kubuntu. Thanks again