# Software updater crashing repeatedly in 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, update-manager

I get `Send error report` every time I try to look for Software Updates through `Software and updates`. Currently, I clicked on it and nothing happens.

I tried to update using `sudo apt-get update`. In Terminal I get a lot of error saying not signed as seen below

```
E: Repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'LP-PPA-tista-plata-theme' to 'Ubuntu'
E: Repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'Plata-theme' to 'Ubuntu'
E: Repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'focal' to 'focal-updates'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Clearsigned file '/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease' contains unsigned lines.
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

There is also this error icon and drop down on the top bar since last 2 weeks

[image]

Update 1 :

tried `sudo apt update` as per the comment by+Kulfy

```
Release file created at: Thu, 08 Oct 2020 11:47:42 +0000
Get:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [207 kB]
Get:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [264 kB]
Get:20 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [55.6 kB]
Get:21 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [87.9 kB]
Get:22 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]
Get:23 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [12.9 kB]
Get:24 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages [16.2 kB]
Get:25 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [171 kB]
Get:26 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [25.3 kB]
Get:27 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [436 B]
Get:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [755 kB]
Get:29 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [560 kB]
Get:30 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Translation-en [159 kB]
Get:31 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [303 kB]
Get:32 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [200 kB]
Get:33 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [356 kB]
Get:34 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]
Get:35 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [16.5 kB]
Get:36 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [4,356 B]
Get:37 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [21.6 kB]
Get:38 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse Translation-en [5,508 B]
Get:39 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:40 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]
Get:41 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [2,638 B]
Get:42 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]
Get:43 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [596 B]
Reading package lists... Error!                                                
W: GPG error: http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.microsoft.com_repos_code_dists_stable_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: The repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Clearsigned file '/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease' contains unsigned lines.
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Update 2:

Tried `sudo apt update` again

```
$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for myPC: 
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease      
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/webdesigner/deb stable InRelease              
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]      
Get:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease [10.4 kB]      
Ign:6 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                          
Err:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.microsoft.com_repos_code_dists_stable_InRelease into data and signature failed
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease into data and signature failed
Get:8 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco Release [6,598 B]                  
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease          
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [264 kB]
Get:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [303 kB]
Err:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease into data and signature failed
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Hit:15 http://dl.google.com/linux/webdesigner/deb stable Release               
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tista/plata-theme/ubuntu focal InRelease       
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_InRelease into data and signature failed
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
Get:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [520 B]
Get:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [520 B]
Err:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
  File has unexpected size (32 != 520). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:520 [weak]
   - SHA256:a3773bb530cff42a2d0897847644b9d65187c8ecb3556a98641ed51a199bafe0
   - SHA1:dd9a0819692490aaa173d9d4509651e08ec89c2c [weak]
   - MD5Sum:e38999641c7c26e004f9ad328196758b [weak]
  Release file created at: Thu, 08 Oct 2020 11:47:42 +0000
Reading package lists... Error!
W: GPG error: http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.microsoft.com_repos_code_dists_stable_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: The repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-security_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Clearsigned file '/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_focal_InRelease' contains unsigned lines.
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: Did you make changes to your sources.list ?

Comment: @OrganicMarble , No, not that I know of. thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update Google Chrome 70 after change in 'Origin' value?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090676/how-to-update-google-chrome-70-after-change-in-origin-value)

Comment: Instead of `apt-get` use `apt` to accept changes. I believe `plata-theme` doesn't make any sense as the Origin and Label of Ubuntu repository. Strange. You can manually verify the error messages by checking [InRelease](http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease) file.

Comment: @Kulfy tried sudo apt update, no luck. Please see the original post for the Terminal output.

Comment: i see 2 errors something with apt key for microsoft repo. Maybe this will help https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83372  but before you try `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archive/partial/*` And check your filesystems.

Comment: The later mentioned errors and warnings are completely different from previous ones. Also, did you redact some lines from `sudo apt update`'s output?

Comment: @Kulfy No, I think I copy pasted the whole output.  I will do it again. Please give 2 mins

Comment: Hashsum mismatch could be temporary issue. Did you try [nobody's suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2262634) for other errors/warnings?

Comment: Shall I try it ? I waited for bit since those were commands and some typo might have got in.

Comment: Contents of `/var/lib/apt/lists/` will be *re-created* as soon as you run `sudo apt update` and `/var/cache/apt/archive/partial/` contains partially downloaded deb packages.

Comment: Thanks. I used a timeshift restore since it appeared much easier in this condition. I will update if the issue in persists

Comment: @Kulfy looks like I found the culprit. Peek, whenever I install it through Ubuntu software or PPA destroy the Software Updater the way mention in OP. After 2 restores, I am back to this. Either I will have to skip Peek or find an alternative.

Comment: @nobody your commands work like a charm. If you can post it as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i see 2 errors something with apt key for microsoft repo. Maybe this will
[help](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83372)

Note not tested from me.

```
# uninstall code
sudo apt remove code
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
sudo apt update # should succeed now

# download code and reinstall it
    wget -O ~/Downloads/code.deb https://update.code.visualstudio.com          
    /latest/linux-deb-x64/stable
    sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/code.deb
```

Next step erases the information for apt/apt-get what is abvailable in your packages sources

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Run

```
sudo apt update
```

or `sudo apt-get update` to recreate the erased files

the next part erases partial downoades packages.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archive/partial/*
```

Comment: rm -rf commands helped the updater broken after installing Peek. Thanks.